# How does this IF-Conditions in Python work?

Tags: python, if-statement, mergesort

This is a Mergesort i found online and tried to implement. It worked but i am not sure how it works. Can someone please explain to me why/how this if-condition works? Where does the code continue when the first-if statement isnt true anymore. I know how if-condtions work in general but to the lack of indentions and/or 'else' confuses me here.

````
def mergeSort(alist):
   print("Splitting ",alist)
   if len(alist)>1:
       mid = len(alist)//2
       lefthalf = alist[:mid]
       righthalf = alist[mid:]
       #recursion
       mergeSort(lefthalf)
       mergeSort(righthalf)

       i=0
       j=0
       k=0

       while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
           if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
               alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
               i=i+1
           else:
               alist[k]=righthalf[j]
               j=j+1
           k=k+1

       while i < len(lefthalf):
           alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
           i=i+1
           k=k+1

       while j < len(righthalf):
           alist[k]=righthalf[j]
           j=j+1
           k=k+1

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)```
````

Comment: This is a recursive in-place sort.  When the first condition isn't true, nothing has to be done in the call (i.e. meaning only 1 element so no sorting).  [Quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSceec-wEyw) illustrating how mergesort works.

Comment: To expand on Darryl's comment, when the function `mergesort(alist)` is entered, first it prints the list, then asks "Is the list longer than `1` element?". If there is only `1` (or `0`) elements in the list, there's no need to do any sorting, because it is already in order, so it simply exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

This relies on `alist` effectively acting like a global variable, which tends to be a bit frowned upon (especially since it's not declared global). There are also some while loops that could be replaced by list comprehensions.

If the `if` condition is not true, then `alist` has only one element, and so sorting it is trivial: a sorted list of one element is just that list. A list of only element can't be out of order. So the function simply terminates without doing anything, because nothing is needed.

If the `if` condition is true, then function reassigns entries in the list, using recursive calls to itself. Each recursion calls the function on a smaller list, so eventually a list of length one is reached, terminating the recursion. So when the `if` condition is false, the function just returns to the next higher level of recursion.

Because of the way mutable data types such as lists work in Python, when a recursion level changes what's in a particular location of the `alist` that it was passed, it also alters what's in that location in the `alist` of the higher recursion levels. This results in the original `alist` ending up sorted, even though the function doesn't have the `return` keyword and thus doesn't explicitly return anything. This is known as a function operating on the input "in place".

Answer (score -1):

In this code there is no else used - to find the matching else always look for else that starts at the same position(with same indentation) as if.  Since there is no such code, it will exit the function when if condition is not satisfied.